# Leer fichero CSV con PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un documento .csv el cual estoy leyendo con PHP pero necesito meter `input type=text` en las columnas que tengo vacías.

```
<?php
echo "<html><body><table>\n\n";
$f = fopen("documento.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($line as $cell) {
                echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
}
fclose($f);
echo "\n</table></body></html>";
?>
```

Los campos en rojo deberían ser inputs pero no se como meterlos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta y los `1` que se ven me confunden. ¿Qué hay realmente en `$cell`, un solo valor o varios valores? ¿Qué son esos `1` que aparecen en la imagen? ¿qué quieres decir con *necesito meter input type=text en las columnas que tengo vacías*? ¿son columnas que vienen en el .csv? ¿están siempre en esa posición o pueden estar en cualquiera?

Comment: Exacto son columnas que vienen en el CSV, siempre estan en esa posicion todos los datos que hay son datos del CSV y los cuadrados rojos son campos en blanco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si se trata de crear un `input` vacío en las columnas 3 y 5 de la tabla, puedes hacer algo así:

```
<?php
    $html="<html><body><table>";
    $f = fopen("documento.csv", "r");
    $emptyInput="<td><input type=\"text\" value=\"\" /></td>";
    while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
        $html.="<tr>";
            foreach ($line as $cell) {
                    $html.="<td>".htmlspecialchars($cell[0])."</td>".
                           "<td>$cell[1]</td>$emptyInput<td>$cell[3]</td><td>$cell[4]</td>";
            }
            $html.="</tr>";
    }
    fclose($f);
    $html.="</table></body></html>";
    echo $html;
?>
```

Aquí se asume que vienen valores en las columnas 1, 2 y 4 (a juzgar por los `1` que aparecen en la imagen de la pregunta). Si no es así sólo hay que modificar la forma en que concatenas `$html` dentro del `foreach`.

Si lo que quieres es poner un `input` vacío en aquellas columnas que no tengan valores puedes hacer algo así:

```
<?php
    $html="<html><body><table>";
    $f = fopen("documento.csv", "r");
    $emptyInput="<td><input type=\"text\" value=\"\" /></td>";
    while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
        $html.="<tr>";
        $numero = count($line);
        for ($c=0; $c < $numero; $c++) {
            $cellData=trim($line[$c]);
            $html.= ( $cellData==="" ) ? $emptyInput :  "<td>$cellData</td>";
        }
        $html.="</tr>";
    }
    fclose($f);
    $html.="</table></body></html>";
    echo $html;
?>
```

Aquí se verifica si el valor de la celda está vacío, poniendo en el  `td` un input cuando esto ocurra o bien el valor de la celda si esta contiene datos.

Comment: Wow, excelente muchas gracias! Como podría hacer para sumar los datos insertados en 1 columna y sumar los datos insertados en la otra columna?

Comment: @MiguelÁngelMartín no entendí lo de sumar.

Comment: Tengo las dos columnas, en los inputs de la primera columna quiero rellenarlos con números al darle un botón enviar me sume todos los de la primera columna por un lado y todos los de la segunda columna columna por otro lado

Comment: @MiguelÁngelMartín ese es ya otro asunto. Deberías plantearlo en una nueva pregunta, pues Stackoverflow funciona por preguntas, para que los casos expuestos queden diferenciados y puedan servir a futuros usuarios con ese problema en específico. Saludos.

Comment: Estoy intentando usar el primer código pero me dice lo siguiente:Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/proyecto/layout/autoevaluacion.php on line 8

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/proyecto/layout/autoevaluacion.php on line 9

Comment: @MiguelÁngelMartín ¿podrías mostrar el código o lo que hay en las líneas `8` y `9`?

Comment: $html.="<td>".htmlspecialchars($cell[0])."</td>"."<td>$cell[1]</td>$emptyInput<td>$cell[3]</td><td>$cell[4]</td>";

Comment: @MiguelÁngelMartín puede que no haya 4 columnas en `$cell`, haz una prueba con `var_dump($cell);` y revisa cuantos valores tiene, debe tener al menos índices del 0 al 4.

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que hacer lo siguiente:

```
 <?php
    echo "<html><body><table>\n\n";
    $f = fopen("documento.csv", "r");
    while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
            echo "<tr>";
            $cont = 0;
            foreach ($line as $cell) {
                    if ($cont !== 0){
                        echo "<td> <input type='text' value='" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "' /></td>";
                    }else{
                        echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
                    }
$cont = $cont + 1;     
            }
            echo "</tr>\n";
    }
    fclose($f);
    echo "\n</table></body></html>";
    ?>
```

Comment: De esta manera todos los campos se convierten en input, yo solo quiero las columnas señaladas

Comment: Ahí le agregue un pequeño cambio al código

Comment: Es como si no entrase en el if primero, pasa al else y no muestra ningun input

Comment: Claro me falto agregar que se vaya cambiando el cont.